# Apache2 - PHP doesn't work (Unifi portal)

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, mysql, php

I am trying to make a [simple authorization web page](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/204950374-UniFi-Custom-Portal-With-Individual-Usernames-and-Passwords-), but their manual is not much informative how to do it. I understand those files and what they do, but I can’t make apache2 work as I need. I am very new to this.

I installed `apache2`, `mysql`, `php`, `phpmyadmin` on Ubuntu 16.04 server. Those are working fine.

I coppied all files (`.htaccess`, `auth.php`, `config.php.inc`, `index.php`, `hotspot.sql`) to the folder `/var/www/guest/s/default/` (I don’t understand why they choosed this folder).

I imported `hotspot.sql` in PHPMyAdmin GUI to the hotspot database.

Now I copied default conf for website to create mine:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/portal.conf
```

I changed line DocumentRoot to:
`DocumentRoot /var/www/guest/s/default`

I enabled my virtual host and disabled default

```
sudo a2ensite portal.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now if I type my IP in web browser, it shows this:
**Direct Access is not allowed**

I even tried these two commands, but I don’t know what they do - something with permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/guest/s/default
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

**EDIT**: If I cp files to `/var/www/html` (I also enabled `000-default.conf` and disabled `portal.conf`) and type to browser `server_ip/index.php`, it says: **Direct Access is not allowed**. But if I try my php file (`server_ip/test.php`) with echo that I created by `sudo vim /var/www/html/test.php`, it works, it says what’s in echo.

`sudo ls -l /var/www/html` shows me that permissions are same for every file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
```

**EDIT2**: The site is actually working thats why it says `Direct Access is not allowed` Its in `index.php` in `else`... But now I have new problem..., If I use it right (meaning from mobile phone wifi) it redirects me correctly, when I try to load some web page but it says

> Not found
>
> The requested URL /guest/s/default was not found on this server.

Looks like the script is trying to connect to `server_ip/guest/s/default` but it doesn't work. I think I try to cp files to /var/www/html again and see what it does...

**EDIT3**: So it says the same:

> Not found
>
> The requested URL /guest/s/default was not found on this server.

Is it possible to make /guest/s/default accesible? How pls?

Comment: The message you are getting is issued from the downloaded `index.php`. Therefore the problem lies in the downloaded files or their incorrect usage and your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is accesible, looks like they have mistake in that manual page. The controler looks for path `server_ip/guest/s/default` not for `server_ip/`.